# Rewrite condition and rule to switch port

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We have webmail on a server on port 81 and www.example.com:81/webmail/ will work for any domain on the server.  However, we want to redirect the people that enter www.example.com/webmail/ to port 81.

It needs to work for all domains so www.example2.com/webmail/ should be redirected to www.example2.com:81/webmail/

I have tried the following which works but redirects everything - how to I append the /webmail directory request to the condition?

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^:]+)(:[0-9]+)?$

RewriteRule ^ http:// %1 : 81 /webmail [R,L]`

(note, I had to add spaces as an error was generated when I tried to submit)

This code will be in a .conf file in /etc/httpd/conf.d, in case that makes any difference.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^81$
RewriteRule ^webmail/?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:81/webmail [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick with a small change. I added (.*) to the rewrite rule to make ^(.*)webmail/?$ - now it works a charm!